# How to setup git when a branch info should not be accessed from certain machines?

Tags: git, branch

I work on **two distinct projects** (i.e. two bunch of files). **Some files are common** (identical) to both projects, **some are different and confidential**: this means ***they should never appear in the project they do not belong to***, neither themselves nor their history as git commit objects.

For the sake of simplicity, let's assume each project has only one machine. Network access from any machine to the other is not available.

I am wondering which git 'installation' I should make ; I am thinking of the following:

- **3 branches**, named `projectA`, `projectB` and `common`
- **one repository on an USB key** to be able to communicate between machines, with only the `common`, branch
- when a modif is made on `projectA` on machine A, it is merged to common on machine A, then common is updated on machine B via the USB key repository, then merged to `projectB`

Would this be the way to go there? Is there a simpler solution?

How could I create a repository with only one branch?

Additional info:

- git version is 1.7.1 (unfortunately not upgradable)
- the confidentiality is machine-related (the files should simply not be present on the wrong machine) and is totally independant from any user rights on said machines

Comment: Are these machines completely disconnected from any network? Can't you just put this repository on the server?

Comment: Couldn't you put the common files in a submodule shared by the 2 repositories?

Comment: @BugHunter there is no server, just two machines outside any network.

Comment: @Philippe I have never used the submodules so I did not think of that. Thanks for the ideal, I'm gonna check it out.

Comment: To transfer commits, perhaps you could also have a look at `git bundle`